# Changing level of some columns in multi index

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame that is looking like this (DATA is the year and month of the order) :

| CUSTOMER_ID | NAME | DATA | COFFEE_SOLD(KG) | WATER_SOLD(L) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | ALEX | 2022 - 01 | 3 | 4 |
| 10000 | ALEX | 2022 - 01 | 5 | 6 |
| 10000 | ALEX | 2022 - 02 | 7 | 8 |
| 10001 | JOE | 2022 - 02 | 1 | 1 |
| 10001 | JOE | 2022 - 03 | 1 | 0 |

I pivoted the df with :

```
df_rap = df_rap.pivot_table(index=["CUSTOMER_ID",'NAME',],columns=["DATA"], values=['COFFEE_SOLD(KG)','WATER_SOLD(L)'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

The result :

|  | CUSTOMER_ID | NAME | COFFEE_SOLD(KG) | COFFEE_SOLD(KG) | COFFEE_SOLD(KG) | WATER_SOLD(L) | WATER_SOLD(L) | WATER_SOLD(L) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATA |  |  | 2022 - 01 | 2022 - 02 | 2022 - 03 | 2022 - 01 | 2022 - 02 | 2022 - 03 |
| 0 | 10000 | ALEX | 8 | 7 | 0 | 10 | 8 | 0 |
| 1 | 10001 | JOE | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

The format is ok but I want to export it to excel. For that I need the data frame to look like this :

|  |  |  | COFFEE_SOLD(KG) | COFFEE_SOLD(KG) | COFFEE_SOLD(KG) | WATER_SOLD(L) | WATER_SOLD(L) | WATER_SOLD(L) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATA | CUSTOMER_ID | NAME | 2022 - 01 | 2022 - 02 | 2022 - 03 | 2022 - 01 | 2022 - 02 | 2022 - 03 |
| 0 | 10000 | ALEX | 8 | 7 | 0 | 10 | 8 | 0 |
| 1 | 10001 | JOE | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

In other words, i would like to lower the level of the first 2 column ( in header ),  to save it in excel properly.

I tried :

df.reset_index()

And it dosen't work.

EDIT :

With :

```
display( df_copy.columns)
```

I saw the format of the columns :

```
MultiIndex([('CUSTOMER_ID', ''),
            ('NAME',        ''),
            ('COFFEE_SOLD(KG)', '2022 - 01'),
            ('COFFEE_SOLD(KG)', '2022 - 02'),
            ('COFFEE_SOLD(KG)', '2022 - 03'),
            ('WATER_SOLD(L)', '2022 - 01'),
            ('WATER_SOLD(L)', '2022 - 02'),
            ('WATER_SOLD(L)', '2022 - 03'),],
           names=[None, 'DATA'])
```

I expected to be :

```
MultiIndex([('', 'CUSTOMER_ID'),
            ('',        'NAME'),
            ('COFFEE_SOLD(KG)', '2022 - 01'),
            ('COFFEE_SOLD(KG)', '2022 - 02'),
            ('COFFEE_SOLD(KG)', '2022 - 03'),
            ('WATER_SOLD(L)', '2022 - 01'),
            ('WATER_SOLD(L)', '2022 - 02'),
            ('WATER_SOLD(L)', '2022 - 03'),],
           names=[None, 'DATA'])
```

Thank you !

Comment: It's unclear.. what are those `empty sapces?` Are those are `empty values` or `mutli-Index`?...

Comment: Hello, I think it's multi-Index because i used pivot function on the data frame.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to overwrite the column values:

```py
cols = [('', 'CUSTOMER_ID'), ('', 'NAME'),]
for t in df_rap.columns[2:]:
    cols.append(t)
    
df_rap.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
```

This leads to a data frame without the word `DATA` in it. Which somehow makes sense, as `DATA` has lost some of it's meaning - now being just the name of the index column. If you nevertheless need to keep `DATA`, you could create a new column with the corresponding values, rename all columns and move the `DATA` column to the front (and save the data frame without the new index column) :

```py
# create a new DATA column
df_rap['DATA'] = df_rap.index
# set new values for the column headers (this time including the new DATA column)
cols = [('', 'CUSTOMER_ID'), ('', 'NAME'),]
for t in df_rap.columns[2:-1]:
    cols.append(t)
cols.append(('', 'DATA'))
df_rap.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
# reorder columns ('DATA' to the front)
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
df_rap = df_rap[cols]
```

Comment: Thank you ! I did something similar with your help  :

for t in df_final.columns[len(cols):]: cols.append(t)